# Why primitive root exists for modulo 4?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

According to Apostol's ANT,

> The smallest positive integer $f$ such that $$a \equiv 1 \mod m$$ is called the exponent of $a$ modulo $m$, and is denoted by writing $$f = \exp_m(a).$$ If $\exp_m(a) = \phi(m)$ then $a$ is called a primitive root mod $m$.

Then later the book says that

> ... primitive roots exist for the modulus 4.

For $m=4$ we have $\phi(4)=2$. If we suppose that $\gcd(a,m)=1$ then $a$ is any odd number. So we must show that $a^2 \equiv 1 \ \text{(mod m)}$ is possible and $a^1 \equiv 1 \ \text{(mod m)}$ is not. However for infinity many odd numbers of the form $a=4k-1 : a \equiv 1 \text{(mod m)}$ which means $f=1<2=\phi(4)=2$.

Where am I wrong? or is the text's mistake?

Comment: Presumably you want to say $a^f \equiv 1 \mod m$

Comment: @RossMillikan, that's right; and f=1.

Comment: No, $f$ depends on $a$ and $m$.  The statement is the definition of $f$ in terms of $a,m$

Comment: @RossMillikan, sorry I don't understand. If there is no $f<\phi(m)$ such that $a \equiv 1 \mod m$, a is called a primitive root mod m. But there exists $f=1$.

Comment: $f$ is the power of $a$ such that $a^f \equiv 1 \pmod m$.  If $a \not \equiv 1, a^1 \not \equiv 1$

Comment: a primitive root modulo $m$, aka a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$ is useful since it allows us to write any $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$ as $a \equiv g^{b} \bmod m$ where $b = \log_{g, \bmod m}(a)$ is the discrete logarithm of $a$. Of course this is possible iff $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic

Answer (score 1):

By your definition, $3$ is a primitive root$\mod 4$, because $3 \not \equiv 1 \pmod 4,3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and $\phi(4)=2$.  As you say, any integer of the form $4k+3$ would also qualify.  The later statement that you quote, "primitive roots exist only for the modulus 4" is not correct.  $2 \text { and }3$ are primitive roots modulo $5$.  For example $2^2 \equiv 4, 2^3 \equiv 3, 2^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $\phi (5)=4$.  There are primitive roots modulo any prime and some composites.  Please look around where you found that statement and see if there is some qualification.

Comment: I think I found where I am wrong; it is supposed be **for all** $a$ with $\gcd(a,m)=1$ such that $a^f \equiv 1 \pmod m$. Because already for all $a$ with $\gcd(a,m)=1$ we have $a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod m$. And $3$ is a counterexample as $3 \not \equiv 1 \pmod 4,3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Am I right?